# Ubuntu openGL issues

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, opengl

my OpenGL doesn't work at all i get

```
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
```

lspci output

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0126] (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:1246] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

dmesg | grep -i nvid

```
    [    9.469068] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
[    9.538786] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: power state changed by ACPI to D0
[    9.538792] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: power state changed by ACPI to D0
[    9.538796] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0006 -> 0007)
[    9.538803] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
[    9.538809] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: setting latency timer to 64
[    9.538942] NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  304.48  Sun Sep  9        
[10300.955799] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: restoring config space at offset 0xf (was 0x100, writing 0x10b)
[10300.955803] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: restoring config space at offset 0xc (was 0x0,  writing 0xfff80000)
[10300.955807] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: restoring config space at offset 0x9 (was 0x1, writing 0x4001)
[10300.955811] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: restoring config space at offset 0x7 (was 0xc, writing 0xd000000c)
[10300.955814] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: restoring config space at offset 0x5 (was 0xc, writing 0xc000000c)
[10300.955817] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: restoring config space at offset 0x4 (was 0x0, writing 0xf0000000)
[10300.955820] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: restoring config space at offset 0x3 (was 0x800000, writing 0x10)
[10300.955823] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: restoring config space at offset 0x1 (was 0x100006, writing 0x100007)
```

my computer is a dell XPS l702x

Comment: What laptop/notebook model is this?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you haven't enabled the Nvidia driver.  Click on the Dash icon in launcher, search for Add  and select the additional drivers icon.  I am using the Nvidia current, without even the post release updates and have driver version 304.64.
Check the Nvidia driver you are running with the command:

```
dmesg | grep -i nvid
```

The output should contain a line like:
[   20.731109] NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86 Kernel Module  304.64  Tue Oct 30 11:09:29 PDT 2012
which gives the driver version number.

OK, you have an older 304 driver, which should work.  Check that the libglx library link is in place

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/libglx.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 Nov  6 19:54 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/libglx.so -> libglx.so.304.64
$ ls -l /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 51 Jun 13  2012 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules -> /etc/alternatives/i386-linux-gnu_xorg_extra_modules
$ ls /etc/alternatives/i386-linux-gnu_xorg_extra_modules
libglx.so  libglx.so.304.64  nvidia_drv.so
```

The file /var/log/Xorg.0.log should contain a section like:
[    21.014] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    21.014] (II) Loading /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/libglx.so
[    21.087] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    21.087]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    21.087]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[    21.087] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  304.64  Tue Oct 30 11:31:18 PDT 2012
[    21.087] (II) Loading extension GLX

List the OpenGL packages you have on your system with:

```
dpkg -l |egrep -i " GL |glx|opengl"
```

The output along with many compiz lines on my system has:

```
libgl1-mesa-dri  9.0-0ubuntu1       free implementation of the OpenGL API -- DRI modules 
libgl1-mesa-glx  9.0-0ubuntu1        free implementation of the OpenGL API -- GLX runtime libglapi-mesa    9.0-0ubuntu1        free implementation of the GL API -- shared library 
libglew1.6       1.6.0-4             OpenGL Extension Wrangler - runtime environment libglewmx1.6     1.6.0-4             OpenGL Extension Wrangler - runtime environment libglu1-mesa     8.0.4-0ubuntu0.2    Mesa OpenGL utility library (GLU) 
libqt4-opengl    4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.3  Qt 4 OpenGL module
libxcb-glx0      1.8.1-1ubuntu0.1    X C Binding, glx extension 
mesa-utils       8.0.1+git20110129+d8f7d6b-0ubuntu2 Miscellaneous Mesa GL utilities
```

Maybe you should update your system in a virtual terminal with the commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

To at least get updated Nvidia drivers, There were pretty serious problems until at least 304.50? on my system.

Comment: His GPU is probably too new for the 304 driver stating the lspci output still unsure. Also, this appears to be a Optimus related issue.

Comment: IM USING A 555M ITS NOT A Optimus ITS A GEFORCE

Comment: @Dank101 It's at least a switchable graphics (hybrid) set up, right? You have both an integrated and discrete one and you appear to be running a mobile (M-suffixed) type of GPU. So this is either regular hybrid graphics or Optimus technology. And no, [numerical IDs say](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/304.43/README/supportedchips.html) it's 550M, not 555M. Please clarify.

Comment: im not sure if its optimus or hybrid

Comment: GeForce GT 555M

Comment: i don't have the OpenGL files