# Xubuntu + Steam != CounterStrike:Source

Tags: apt, updates, steam, opengl

I recently bought [this computer](https://gist.github.com/IoannisGavras/526e76fe8053bf41711c) from a used equipment auction. I installed Xubuntu [Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (32 bit)] and decided to try if I can play CounterStrike:Source using Steam here. After installation, I got this message:

["Could not find required OpenGL entry point 'glGetError'! Either your video card is unsupported, or your OpenGL driver needs to be updated."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17R7c.jpg)

I tried a few remedies advised on-line, like

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install xorg-x11-drv-catalyst-devel.i686 xorg-x11-drv-catalyst-libs.i686
```

but got no results.

Answer (score 0):

Are your video-drivers up-to-date?

Open an Terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and chek if you can update them with the package `xserver-xorg-video-all`.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic xserver-xorg-video-all libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
```

This must resolve the problem.

Comment: I did it and got: 
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libgl1-mesa-dri is already the newest version.
libgl1-mesa-glx is already the newest version.
xserver-xorg-core is already the newest version.
xserver-xorg-video-all is already the newest version.
linux-headers-generic is already the newest version.
linux-headers-generic set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: Does this help? http://askubuntu.com/questions/236362/ubuntu-opengl-issues

Comment: Not really: Video Card:
Driver: Intel Open Source Technology Center Mesa DRI Intel(R) Q33 x86/MMX/SSE2
Driver Version: 1.4 Mesa 10.1.0
OpenGL Version: 1.4
Desktop Color Depth: 24 bits per pixel
Monitor Refresh Rate: 60 Hz
VendorID: 0x8086
DeviceID: 0x29d2
Number of Monitors: 1
Number of Logical Video Cards: 1
Primary Display Resolution: 1280 x 1024
Desktop Resolution: 1280 x 1024
Primary Display Size: 13,31" x 10,63" (17,01" diag)

Comment: Can you run `glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version string"`?

Comment: kotiyksi@kotiyksiKone:~$ glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version string"
OpenGL version string: 1.4 Mesa 10.1.0